# Cannot change APFS encryption password

Tags: disk-utility, password, encryption, filevault, apfs

I have a clean install of macOS High Sierra with APFS Encrypted file partition. 
During install I checked the "decrypt at login" option, but each have a different password. I now want to change my APFS password but I haven't been abled to:

- "change password" is greyed out in the Disk Utility for my APFS volume.
- `diskutil apfs changePassphrase ...`  returned an error saying it can't do it.

Any idea how I can do that?

P.S. I also have FileVault turned on, with the same password as my login (so different from the APFS Encryption).

Answer (score 11):

You need to list your disks to find the APFS volume disk where you want to change the password:

```
sudo diskutil apfs list
```

Now find the UUID of the cryptographic Disk User:

```
sudo diskutil apfs listUsers <your APFS volume, like: disk1s1>
```

Finally you can change the APFS volume password:

```
sudo diskutil apfs changePassphrase <your APFS volume, like: disk1s1> -user <the Disk User cryptographic UUID, like: 12345678-1234-1234-1234567890AB>
```